# Firestore + Cloud Functions: multiple condition clauses

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I can't seem to combine two "where" clauses in a Cloud function (the Firestore document isn't updated). Would greatly appreciate if someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

```
return admin.firestore().collection('/events/')
  // .where('data', '<', new Date()).where('published', '==', true) // Doesn't work (multiple)
  // .where('data', '<', new Date()) // Works (single)
  // .where('published', '==', true) // Works (single)
  .get().then(
    (result: any) => {
      if (result.size > 0) {
        result.forEach(async (doc: any) => {
          await doc.ref.update({
            'published': false,
          })
        await sgMail.send(msg);
      })
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), `You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field, and you can include at most one array_contains clause in a compound query. However, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array-contains), make sure to create a composite index`. More info can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what isn't working the way you expect.  If there is an error, be sure to copy the error message into the question.

Comment: @sllopis Ok, that makes sense! When working with Flutter, I get those index URL's automatically generated in console - but I'll have to manually create those when writing Functions. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @DougStevenson Unfortunately I don't have any errors to share - the only "error" is that the document wasn't being updated. sllopis's solution above was the ticket though.

Comment: I'm seeing that you're not doing any error handling in your code.  Capturing error messages would make these things easier to diagnose in the future.  The error message would have told you want was wrong and what to do next.

Comment: Hi, I will go ahead and post my comment as an answer for greater visibility to other community users. Please, also consider doing what @DougStevenson suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries):**

> **You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field, and you can include at most one array_contains clause in a compound query. However, in your case, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array-contains), make sure to create a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).**